# linq-to-sql orderby and select null entries

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
var TheOutput = from u in MyDC.TheTable
                where ....
                orderby u.TheDateTimeUsed
                select new MyModel()
                {
                   ....
                   TheDateCreated = u.TheDateTimeCreated,
                   TheDateUsed = u.TheDateTimeUsed
                   ...

                };

return TheOutput.Take(10).ToList();
```

u.DateTimeUsed is a nullable date. If the value is null, then I want these records to appear first in the list of 10 that I'm loading.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107767/ordering-nullable-datetime-in-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var TheOutput = from u in MyDC.TheTable
                where ....
                orderby !u.TheDateTimeUsed.HasValue
                orderby u.TheDateTimeUsed
                select new MyModel()
                {
                   ....
                   TheDateCreated = u.TheDateTimeCreated,
                   TheDateUsed = u.TheDateTimeUsed
                   ...

                };
```

You can also do it like this:

```
var TheOutput = from u in MyDC.TheTable
                where ....
                orderby u.TheDateTimeUsed??DateTime.MinValue
                select new MyModel()
                {
                   ....
                   TheDateCreated = u.TheDateTimeCreated,
                   TheDateUsed = u.TheDateTimeUsed
                   ...

                };
```

Not as nice as the first one.